# Trying to figure out if an array is sorted

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to find out if the array a user inputs is sorted or not (not trying to sort it though). If the user's input is in ascending order from least to greatest, I want to write a message saying "the input is sorted" and if not "the user input is NOT sorted".

**This is my code so far:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] array = new int[20];
    int n = 0;
    char Continue;

    InputArray(array, ref n);
    IsSorted(array, n);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", IsSorted(array, n));

    do{


        Console.Write("Would you like to continue? Y/N : ");
        Continue = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        Continue = char.ToUpper(Continue);

      }while(Continue != 'N');

}

    public static void InputArray(int[] array, ref int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    Console.Write("Enter a number of elements under 20: ");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (n < 0 || n > 20)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number greater than zero and less than 20: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} elements:", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} elements:", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }

}

   public static bool IsSorted(int[] array, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;      
}

}
```

I keep getting true no matter what in this case...

Answer (score 4):

Your method returns `true` as soon as condition is met for first and second items, without checking all other elements.

```
public static bool IsSorted(int[] array, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i - 1] > array[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I made two changes:

1. Return `false` early, but wait with returning `true` until end of loop is reached.
2. Your solution would throw `ArrayOutOfBoundException`, because of `i + 1` index access. It's easier to start from `i = 1`, go to `i < array.Lenght`, and use `i - 1` within an indexer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the LINQ operators like this:

```
public static bool IsSorted(int[] array, int n)
{
    return
        array
            .Skip(1)
            .Zip(array, (a1, a0) => a1 - a0)
            .All(a => a >= 0);  
}
```